# WP-INCLUDES folder returning error 403

Tags: wordpress, windows, ssl, iis, cloudflare

I have a website on WordPress with SSL installed through Cloudflare. My server has a Windows/IIS operating system.

I have a issue on the WP-INCLUDES folder returning error 403 with several WordPress and Template functions not working.

I would like to know if any of you guys know how to fix this issue and could help me. I’ve already set all permissions on IIS but without success.

If you need more details you can check the website on www.sospdf.com.br.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do with the wp-includes folder? I believe it is common for wp-includes to be forbidden as it can be a security liability. If you're changing something in the wp-includes folder you may want to do this through SFTP.

If pages other than /wp-includes/ are returning 403 or forbidden here are some of the most common causes:

1.) 403 caused by a wordpress plugin, particularly a poorly configured security plugin. Deactivate plugins and reactivate one at a time

2.) Corrupt .htaccess file. Download your .htaccess file via FTP so you have a back up copy. Delete .htaccess from your server and then generate a new

.htaccess by logging into your theme admin and going to settings >> permalinks
3.) Check file permissions (which is seems like you did)

More information on the rationale behind why it might be better for your WP-INCLUDES folder to return 403 can be found in the Wordpress Codex on [hardening wordpress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress) in the WP-INCLUDES section.

Comment: Thank you Merrill Cook, but I believe you didn't read carefully my question.

I'm using a Windows/IIS platform, so I don't have .HTACCESS or SFTP.


The website was fully functional before I changed it to HTTPS (CLOUDFLARE SSL), after that change the WP-INCLUDES error occurred.

I'm applied all the WINDOWS/IIS you suggested but without success.
 I've posted here as an last resort to see if any of the guys here had this issue before and could help me.